# Good strategy for crosscutting concern

Tags: spring, jsf

Can somebody point me a good strategy for security crosscutting concern without AOP for a JSF-Spring-Hibernate web application?

Security context (in user's web session) must be accesible in Business (for rules and authorization) and Data Access Layer (to store user name in BD)

I can use Spring IOC but my boss doesn't allow me to use AOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Spring Security's [SecurityContextHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e1543) which uses a ThreadLocal to store the current user's credentials. Then you can just access it as necessary from the business layer and the DAOs, at the cost of coupling these to the Spring framework.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please, allow me a few questions. Is SecurityContextHolder safe for a Web Application? Can every logged user access to its own security context? How persist the context betwen a request and the next? Because in a web app every request has its own thread. Or maybe I need to set the security context in the SecurityContextHolder in every request and start the business logic flow.

Comment: I think the Spring Security documentation can answer your questions much better than I can. It is safe and designed for a Web Application, and the framework has various strategies for persisting the context between requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Java EE Interceptors](http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_134_interceptors_1_1) but it might be little more difficult to set up than Spring AOP since you are already using Spring stack.